# How does QFT describe an electron in a magnetic field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, wavefunction

Is the electron represented by some kind of wavepackage (localized in space) or by a Fock state and not localized in space? Does then a collapse of the wavefunction occur when one sees the points of the track? If these are Fock states is there not superluminality in the collapse?